# How to get the index in an associative array loop coffeescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, associative-array

I've been looking for answers for quite some time now and none of what I've seen is right for my situation. Here is my code:

```
colors: 
    red : "255, 0, 0"
    blue : "24, 149, 207"
    green : "74, 165, 76"
    grey : "202, 202, 202"
    black : "0, 0, 0"
    yellow : "183, 118, 4"
    purple : "83, 74, 166"
    white : "255, 255, 255"


for color, rgb, index of colors
 console.log index
```

I know that it is not working and I've seen many post about a simple array with a loop that looks like that:

```
for color, index in colors
    console.log index
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do something like that with associative array or if I have to create define an index variable like this:

```
index: 0
for color, rgb of colors
    console.log index
    index++
```

Comment: Yes, you have to do it yourself. CS's `for ... of` loop is just a JavaScript `for ... in` loop in disguise. An `index` option in the CS `for ... in` loop make sense because you're iterating over something inherently ordered; an `index` when iterating over an object makes less sense because objects are inherently unordered so the index has no useful relation to what you're iterating over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your problem correctly. Do you want to loop over all your colors? Then do it like this:

```
colors =
    red : "255, 0, 0"
    blue : "24, 149, 207"

index = 0
for color, rgb of colors
    console.log color
    console.log rgb
    console.log index
    index++
```

Note that you have to use `colors =` instead of `colors:` to define a variable.

Comment: I do have to loop on the colors, but I want to have an index for every colors, not only the key. I would like to be able to access a variable that increment on the loop... Example: red = 0, blue = 1, etc. Do I have to create that index myself or is there a way to have it automatically?

Comment: An index doesn't really make sense here because the standard does not determine an object property order. You should add an index manually.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I wanted to know